# how to get the XML data whose record state is other than Original using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Consider  I have an xml like below

```
<x> 
<groupRecord> 
 <p1><![CDATA[kk]]></p1> 
    <x1> 
      <groupRecord lineNumber=0  recordState=0 >
            <c1><![CDATA[1]]></c1> 
            <x2> 
               <groupRecord lineNumber=0 recordState=1 >
                <c2><![CDATA[1]]></c2> </groupRecord> 
            </x2>
            <x3> 
             <groupRecord>
              <c3><![CDATA[FFD]]></c3>
              </groupRecord>
            </x3>
        </groupRecord>
     </x1>
    </groupRecord>
 </x>
```

If you observe at each groupRecord level I have an attribute called recordState this will help in knowing whether data is getting modified-4 or deleted-3 or inserted-1 or updated-2 or orginal-0.
Now by using jquery how to get the XML Data whose recordState is other than original at each nodel level.
It would be helpful if it can be achieved by XML as well

Comment: have you tried using jQuery parse xml http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Comment: @Archer var length = $(dataXML).find('groupRecord[recordState!= 0]').length; I have tried like this but it is giving information about the groupRecord which doesn't have recordState as well